# Error while creating table on TableDefs.Append showing Invalid Argument

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am writing a program in Access 2013.  If it is the first time they will install the program, it will create an external database (that will be linked later) and will create the tables needed.  In the attached code, I am running through an array that has a list of all the tables needed and using an internal (local) table that has all the fields associated with the particular table.  It runs through the code and creates all the fields just fine, but once it gets to the line db1.TableDefs.Append newTable it throws the Invalid Argument error.  I have searched as much as I can and it appears that my setup is the same as all others and cannot figure out what the issue is.

```
Function CreateDataTables()
Dim db As Database
Dim db1 As Database
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim tblCount As Integer
Dim rst1 As Recordset
Dim newTable As TableDef
Dim newField As Field
Dim newIdx As Index
Dim newType As Variant
Dim newLength As Variant
Dim newPK As String
Dim sysTable As String
Dim SQLstr As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim tblNames() As Variant
Stop

SQLstr = "SELECT DISTINCT tableName "
SQLstr = SQLstr + "FROM sysdata;"

Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(SQLstr, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
tblCount = rst.RecordCount
'Creating array to house table names
ReDim tblNames(tblCount)
tblNames() = rst.GetRows(tblCount)

Set db = Nothing
Set rst = Nothing

Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("sysdata", dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
'Create database reference to newly created database in prior function
Set db1 = OpenDatabase(dbFileLoc)

For x = 1 To tblCount
    'Create new tabledef
    Set newTable = db1.CreateTableDef(tblNames(0, (x - 1)))
    'Loop through each record of particular table (named in rst) to create each field
    Do While rst.Fields("tableName") = tblNames(0, (x - 1))
        newType = rst.Fields("typeData")
        newLength = rst.Fields("lengthField")
        newPK = Nz(rst.Fields("PKey"), "No")
        Set newField = newTable.CreateField(rst.Fields("fieldName"))
        With newField
            .Type = newType
            If Not IsNull(newLength) Then .Size = newLength
            'If field is indicated as a PK, this will create the PK
            If newPK = "Yes" Then
                With newTable
                    newField.Attributes = dbAutoIncrField
                    Set newIdx = .CreateIndex("PrimaryKey")
                    newIdx.Fields.Append newIdx.CreateField(tblNames(0, (x - 1)))
                    newIdx.Primary = True
                    .Indexes.Append newIdx
                End With
            End If
        End With
        'Append field
        newTable.Fields.Append newField

        rst.MoveNext
        If rst.EOF Then Exit Do
    Loop
    MsgBox "Table " + newTable.NAME + " create", vbOKOnly  'Placed to verify loop was completed and showing table name
    '''The line below gives the Invalid Argument error
    '''Do not know what is causing this
    db1.TableDefs.Append newTable
    db1.TableDefs.Refresh
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up figuring out that the numbers in my sysdata table that was designating the Field Type were wrong.  I even got the from a MSDN site.  I ran through a loop to determine the actual number of the data types and then placed them in the table and it worked!  I also located another bug in the code having to do with the Primary Key.  Where I'm appending the Index, in the CreateField I have the Table name and not the Field name.  Once I changed that, the PK populated as it should too.